# terminal in Tmux is 256color but vim isn't

Tags: ubuntu, vim, tmux, colors

Recently I installed tmux on my Ubuntu 16.04.

The terminal screen in `tmux` shows 256 color correctly however when I opened `vim` within `tmux`, the color was different from what it showed when it was run directly on the terminal.

I tried to add

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

in my `.tmux.conf` file but the problem still exists.

- my terminal screen in `tmux`: [image: Terminal screen in tmux]
- `vim` run directly on the terminal: [image: vim run directly on the terminal]
- `vim` run within `tmux`: [image: vim run within tmux]

The output of

```
echo $TERM; tput colors; tput longname
```

- outside tmux:

  ```
  xterm-256color
  256
  xterm
  ```
- with 256 colors inside tmux:

  ```
  screen-256color
  256
  GUN Screen with 256 colors
  ```

Comment: All that `vim` cares about is the `$TERM` variable. Please provide the output of the following both inside `tmux`, and outside: `echo $TERM; tput colors; tput longname`

Comment: @Patrick Hi Patrick, here are the output:
outside tmux: xterm-256color, 256, xterm with 256 colors
inside tmux: screen-256color,256, GUN Screen with 256 colors

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
tmux -2
```

From the man page:

> ```
> -2            Force tmux to assume the terminal supports 256 colours.
> ```

You may also have a problem with your terminfo entry for `screen-256color`.

Also try:

```
alias tmux='TERM=xterm-256color tmux -2'
```